# Zero width space shows as underscore

Tags: terminal-emacs, characters

Typing a zero-width space in TERMINAL emacs shows an underscore-ish character.  How to make it showing nothing?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Refer to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Glyphless Chars`

By default the zero-width characters are displayed using the `thin-space` display method which will "Display a thin space, 1-pixel wide on graphical displays, or 1-character wide on text terminals"; also noting that "The ‘thin-space’, ‘empty-box’, ‘hex-code’, and ASCII string display methods are drawn with the ‘glyphless-char’ face" which by default inherits from the `underline` face.

This default ensures that these (potentially-confusing) characters are not 100% invisible to the user, and can easily be made much more visible if desired; but there *is* also a `zero-width` display method which you can use to truly hide them from display:

```el
(set-char-table-range glyphless-char-display
                      (char-from-name "ZERO WIDTH SPACE") 'zero-width)
```

---

*Personally* I want these things to be as visible as possible -- I've encountered a situation where I was unwittingly copying and pasting zero-width joiners between visible characters, and I created a mess because I never knew they were there.  To make sure they are apparent to me (as I don't expect such things to normally be in the text I edit), I use this:

```el
(set-face-background 'glyphless-char "red")
```

(If you want to see how that looks, ‌c‍o‍p‍y​ ‌t‍h‍i‍s​ ‌s‍e‍n‍t‌e‍n‍c‍e​ ‌i‍n‍t‍o​ ‌E‍m‍a‍c‍s​ ‌a‍n‍d​ ‌c‍o‍n‍f‍i‍g‍u‍r‍e​ ‌t‍h‍a‍t​ ‌b‍a‍c‍k‍g‍r‍o‍u‍n‍d‍.)

---

To hide such chars for a particular mode only, you could make the char table buffer-local in that mode.

```el
;; Make glyphless chars highly visible.
(set-face-background 'glyphless-char "red")

;; Hide ZERO WIDTH chars completely in `org-mode'.
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'my-hide-zero-width-chars)

(defun my-hide-zero-width-chars ()
  "Make ZERO WIDTH characters completely invisible."
  (setq-local glyphless-char-display
              my-zero-width-glyphless-char-display))

(defvar my-zero-width-glyphless-char-display
  (let ((table (copy-sequence glyphless-char-display))
        (charnames (list "ZERO WIDTH SPACE"
                         "ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE"
                         "ZERO WIDTH JOINER"
                         "ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER")))
    (dolist (name charnames)
      (set-char-table-range table (char-from-name name) 'zero-width))
    table)
  "Variant of `glyphless-char-display' which hides ZERO WIDTH chars.")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I also want to know what setting makes the zero width space become an underscore like thing.

Comment: Can I hide these only in org-mode?

Comment: n.b. I've updated the answer with all of the additional information and responses from my earlier comments.

Comment: Not working for me. I run that code. In an org buffer I can confirm it partially worked, because if I eval `(aref glyphless-char-display (char-from-name "ZERO WIDTH SPACE"))` I get `zero-width`. But if I then insert that character in my org buffer, I still see an red underscore.

Comment: phils, could a simalar method be used to change the glyph of `NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE`? It is the same as no-break space when using fixed-width font,and it would be useful to be able to distinguish them.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue: for me, in a GUI emacs frame, the narrow no-break space *is* narrow (tested with `emacs -Q` for both Emacs 27 and 28).  I only have "wide narrow glyphs" in terminal frames (which is expected).  If you're not *already* getting narrow glyphs, I'm not sure whether this answer could help; you'd need to play with the code to find out.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. In a GUI frame and starting emacs (28) with `-Q`, `no-break space` is shown as an underlined empty space, which usefully distinguishes it from normal space. But `narrow no-break space` is shown in exactly the same way. Maybe I'll ask a question here about that.

Answer (score 0):

Related to the [above
answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/65109/19526): in emacs 29,
there's
[glyphless-display-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Glyphless-Chars.html). That
shows big boxes for such characters.

That's not what you're asking for, but if you've turned that mode on, you certainly won't be hiding zero-width spaces and similar things. It's also an arguably simpler way to accomplish the red highlighting in the above answer -- and the boxes have the character abbreviations, such as "ZWSP", "ZWJ", "ZWNJ", and so on, which are nice. (Although of course there's `describe-char`.)