# search or occur for text with a certain face, or character properties?

Tags: faces, highlighting, isearch, occur

I'm interested in finding zero-width spaces and similar "glyphless" characters in my buffer -- and more generally, text that's highlighted or has a certain face.

I can show zero-width spaces and similar things by customizing the `glyphless-char-display` (see [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/65108/zero-width-space-shows-as-underscore/65109#65109)) or `glyphless-display-mode`. Those *show* those characters -- but I want to *navigate* them, with some kind of next/previous behavior, like one gets with `isearch` or `occur`.

A very similar use-case is when I've used `highlight-regexp` and I have something highlighted throughout my buffer -- now I want to jump to the next/previous such highlighted bit. Or see a total number of the matches.

Is there some way to do this? It seems like I would be searching/occur'ing for some kind of face/display property? Or perhaps for characters with a certain [Unicode character property/category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was hoping to avoid a solution that avoids having to list all the "weird"/interesting characters -- but if I have to do that, the solution below makes it easy to modify the characters you look for.

(Part of my motivation here came from a bug related to handling `U+00A0`, no-break space. So one could add "NO-BREAK SPACE" to the list below.)

```lisp
    (defun zero-width-occur ()
      "Run occur with a regexp matching various zero-width space, punctuation characters.
Consider using this with `glyphless-display-mode' and `whitespace-mode'.

See https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/general_punctuation/list.htm
    and 
    https://unicode-explorer.com/b/2000 
    and 
    https://www.alanwood.net/unicode/general_punctuation.html"
      (interactive)
      (occur (mapconcat (lambda (name) (char-to-string (char-from-name name)))
               '("ZERO WIDTH SPACE" ; U+200B
                 "ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER" ; U+200C
                 "ZERO WIDTH JOINER" ; U+200D
                 "ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE" ; U+FEFF
                 "WORD JOINER" ; U+2060
    ) "\\|")))
```

For the highlight-regexp stuff, here's what I found I can use with `text-property-search-forward`:

```lisp
    (defun next-highlight ()
      (interactive)
      (defun mypredicate (value property)
        (if (listp property) (member value property))) 
      (text-property-search-forward 'face 'hi-yellow #'mypredicate))
```

Neither is *quite* what I was hoping for, but are a good first step and I hope others find them useful. Improvements welcome.

Answer (score 0):

`C-h f text-property-search`:

> `text-property-search-forward` is an autoloaded interactive
> byte-compiled Lisp function in `text-property-search.el`.
>
> `(text-property-search-forward PROPERTY &optional VALUE PREDICATE NOT-CURRENT)`
>
> Search for next region of text where `PREDICATE` returns non-nil for `PROPERTY`.
>
> `PREDICATE` is used to decide whether the value of `PROPERTY` at a given
> buffer position should be considered as a match for `VALUE`.
> `VALUE` defaults to nil if omitted.
>
> If `PREDICATE` is a function, it will be called with two arguments:
> `VALUE` and the value of `PROPERTY` at some buffer position.  The function
> should return non-`nil` if these two values are to be considered a match.
>
> Two special values of `PREDICATE` can also be used:
> If `PREDICATE` is `t`, that means the value of `PROPERTY` must `equal` `VALUE`
> to be considered a match.
> If `PREDICATE` is `nil` (which is the default), the value of `PROPERTY` will
> match if it is not `equal` to `VALUE`.  Furthermore, a nil `PREDICATE`
> means that the match region ends where the value changes.  For
> instance, this means that if you loop with
>
> ```
> (while (setq prop (text-property-search-forward 'face)) ...)
> ```
>
> you will get all the distinct regions with non-nil `face` values in
> the buffer, and the `prop` object will have the details about the
> match.  See the manual for more details and examples about how
> `VALUE` and `PREDICATE` interact.
>
> If `NOT-CURRENT` is non-`nil`, current buffer position is not examined for
> matches: the function will search for the first region that doesn’t
> include point and has a value of `PROPERTY` that matches `VALUE`.
>
> If no matches can be found, return `nil` and don’t move point.
> If found, move point to the end of the region and return a
> `prop-match` object describing the match.  To access the details
> of the match, use `prop-match-beginning` and `prop-match-end` for
> the buffer positions that limit the region, and `prop-match-value`
> for the value of `PROPERTY` in the region.
>
> Other relevant functions are documented in the text-properties
> group. Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 27.1.

Comment: I couldn't get that to work for the glyphless characters, but for the highlighted regexps, I could: if you've used `M-s h r` and highlighted with the `hi-yellow` face, then this will move to the end of the next highlight: `(defun mypredicate (value property) (if (listp property) (member value property)))` and then do the search with `(text-property-search-forward 'face 'hi-yellow #'mypredicate)`.

Comment: FYI: You can post an answer to your own question, @DanDrake. (And you can accept your own answer as the most helpful.)

Comment: I can't speak for the vanilla Emacs text-property search commands. I've never used them; I just know they added them. ;-)

Comment: I added my code above to my answer -- thanks for finding `text-property-search-forward` for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you use library [Highlight](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) ([`highlight.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el)) you can use commands `hlt-next-highlight` and `hlt-previous-highlight` to navigate to the next/previous occurrence of a given face.

Answer (score 0):

For things like zero-width spaces that have a Unicode representation, you can just use `isearch` or `occur`. The only trick is how to insert the Unicode character into the search string: `C-x 8 RET` does that; e.g. for zero-width space, you can say:

```
C-s C-x 8 RET zero width space RET C-s C-s C-s ...
```

and similarly for other Unicode characters, with each `C-s` taking you to the next occurrence.

You can also cut and paste the Unicode character (which may be easier to do if you highlight them first) into the `isearch` search string.

See [Inserting Text](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Inserting-Text.html) in the Emacs manual.

Comment: I was hoping for something more general -- I want emacs to tell me which characters it has decided are glyphless or have zero width, etc. For example, what if I somehow get a "Mongolian vowel separator" -- https://unicode-explorer.com/c/180E -- in my buffer? I want to find all such "weird" characters without having to list them myself. But my answer below is at least a start.